# Angular6 - 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular6

I am getting the below errors for the below function in Angular 6

```
public getList() {
        return this.http.get(environment.serverUrl +'/vmsdata/v1/tftoport/customer/1001')
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json()
            .then(json => {
                console.log('data', json.items);
                return json.items;
            });
    }
```

For the line `.then(response => response.json()`, Error is
`[ts] Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'`.

For the line `.then(json => {` Error is `[ts] Parameter 'json' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Comment: There's at least one closing parentheses `)` missing in your code.

Comment: Is `this.http` an instance of `Http` or `HttpClient`? And you can get rid of the second error by changing `json => ...` to `(json: any) => ...`, or you can disable noImplicityAny in your tsconfig.json

Comment: In angular 6, the old, deprecated `Http` class does not exist anymore, so it's necessarily `HttpClient`; which converts retrieved data to json by default. So you don't need the  `.then(response => response.json())` line

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 6 You don't need to map data into json because angular 6 provide json by default.